# Can't make eclipse open even after change eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to change eclipse.ini file to add  `-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javaw.exe`

in order to get rid of the error:

> java runtime environment JRE or java development kit must be available
>   in order to run eclipse. No java virtual machine was found after
>   searching in the folloiwng location

But the error still persists, am I doing something wrong?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this Eclipse document](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini):

> **Note the format of the -vm option - it is important to be exact:**
>
> ```
> The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
> The value must be the full absolute or relative path to the Java executable, not just to the Java home directory.
> The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM.
> ```

Note the first requirement.  So, try using this somewhere in your .ini file:

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

**Note:** this is obviously a fragile way to enforce .ini file syntax, and I believe a later version of Eclipse has fixed this potential problem.  But, looking at your file, you seem to have a May 2011 build, and if it's not working, I'd try following the .ini document strictly.

Answer (score 0):

try use the same values for:

**-Xms** and **-Xmx**

example:

-Xms384m
-Xmx384m

this works for me